# Why are my SharePoint downloads not listing total size or time remaining?

Tags: sharepoint

I am testing downloading files from our SharePoint site from outside connections.  When downloading files, you never receive total size of the file or time remaining within the download prompt.

Why is this?  Can this be fixed?  It sort of makes the download experience seem longer than usual with an unknown time remaining.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft decided that the client does not need to know the exact file size, you'll have to accept it: they always decide for you without giving a simple ability to change something :)